# SDL can't read shift if key down happened before initializing, workaround?

Tags: sdl

I'm trying to read the state of the shift keys right after initialising SDL and creating the windows, that is, I want to detect if the shift key is depressed while booting the application.

But although I run the app with shift pressed, it doesn't detect the keys.

If I add the same code inside the main loop, and I start pressing shift *after* the program started running, then it reads the state correctly, so I guess SDL internally only recognizes the keys being pressed if the *key down* event happened while SDL was running.

Might there be an OS-independent way of dealing with this? I'm using MacOS by the way, but want this project to be as OS-independent as it can.

```
// Added either of these but didn't help:
// SDL_PumpEvents();
// SDL_Event event; // while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ));

const Uint8 *keys = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
if( ! keys[SDL_SCANCODE_LSHIFT] and ! keys[SDL_SCANCODE_RSHIFT] ) {
    printf( "Booted without shift." );
}
else {
    printf( "Booted pressing shift." );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SDL relies on event processing to populate the keyboard state array. From the [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState):

> Note: This function gives you the current state after all events have been processed, so if a key or button has been pressed and released before you process events, then the pressed state will never show up in the SDL_GetKeyboardState() calls.

That means you will have to implement it for each platform you want to support, however that should not be too difficult:

```
bool shift_pressed(void)
{
#ifdef WINDOWS
    return GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000
#else
    // Implement for other OS as needed
    return false;
#endif        
}
```